# Nomenclature for a selecting a temporal window?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to know the proper term, so I can Google how to reduce the duration of a video with `ffmpeg`.  For example, assume a 3600 second video that reduced in size by selecting the 2nd and third minute of the video.  This temporal window of time would be from t1=60 to t2=180.

I suspect that cropping would be the correct term because common usage refers to a spacial and temporal reduction of the video.

What is the correct term (i.e. from Google search standpoint) to indicate the said idea of a temporal window?

I would like use this search keyword with ffmpeg to `[temporally slice up a video / audio][1]`.

Comment: Usage in video editing contexts is trimming.

Comment: "trimming" is correct, and connotes a reductive edit.  "marking a range" means simply selecting it by defining the desired beginning and end or "in/out" marks.  Not sure if FFMPEG uses that terminology, but most NLE's do.